# Overlapping TransitionManager animations in android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I am trying to expand and collapse my view with the help of TransitionManager animation. Following is the output,

[image]

See the overlapping layout while collapsing top view. How to avoid that ? I set "detailedView" (one with icons) visibility `GONE` and use following code for animation,

```
topView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(topView);
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(bottomView);
                if (detailsView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    detailsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cardText.setText("Collapse Title");
                } else {
                   detailsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   cardText.setText("Expanded Title");

                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would build the animation differently. I would make a LinearLayout with the top cell with wrap_content, and when clicking I would do something like:

```
 valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(titleContainer.getHeight(),titleContainer.getHeight() + newHeight );
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            titleContainer.setHeight(animation.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
    valueAnimator.setDuration(270);
    valueAnimator.start();
```

Comment: I am glad you liked it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

The first argument that the `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition()` function takes **must be the parent of all the views that will interact in the transition** e.g:

I have the next layout:

```
<!-- The scene root  -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/transition_container" >


    <!-- First card  -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/expandableCard1">

        <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/staticHeader1">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/expandableContent1">
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <!-- Second card  -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/expandableCard2">

        <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/staticHeader2">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/expandableContent2">
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

And my code (kotlin):

```
// toggle
if( expandableContent1.visibility == View.GONE ){

      // apply to the root scene
      TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(transition_container )

      // change the visibility of the expandable content
      expandableContent1.visibility = View.VISIBLE
      arrowBtn.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_arrow_up_24)

} else {

      // apply to the root scene
      TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(transition_container )

      // change the visibility of the expandable content
      expandableContent1.visibility = View.GONE
      arrowBtn.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_arrow_down_24)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set your transition;

```
TransitionSet()
.setOrdering(TransitionSet.ORDERING_SEQUENTIAL)

/**
 * A flag used to indicate that the child transitions of this set
 * should all start at the same time.
 */
public static final int ORDERING_TOGETHER = 0;

/**
 * A flag used to indicate that the child transitions of this set should
 * play in sequence; when one child transition ends, the next child
 * transition begins. Note that a transition does not end until all
 * instances of it (which are playing on all applicable targets of the
 * transition) end.
 */
public static final int ORDERING_SEQUENTIAL = 1;
```